# why does my model look like this

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, eevee-render-engine, workbench-render-engine

I don't know how to really explain this problem besides that my model looks weird in every mode besides workbench and Eevee
[image: workbench]
[image: material preview]
[image: cycles]
[image: eevee]
the final one is Eevee i just forgot to add text
here is the file download https://mega.nz/file/m81n2aYD#MFy4hopOJopsAM_tQdplgJVLKKQSLsyi-Wfvjt4Fm8Q

Comment: You wrote *"my model looks weird in every mode besides workbench and Eevee"* but you mean it looks weird in Eevee and material preview because there is no face, and it looks ok in Cycles and Workbench?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The model looks weird in *Eevee* and *Material Preview* (which is similar to Eevee) because the materials have transparency enabled (*Blend Mode* is set to *Blend*) and *Show Backface* is enabled.

[image: screenshot 1]

Select render engine **Eevee** to see the related material settings.
Select a mesh part, go to the *Material Settings* and untick *Show Backface*. Repeat this for all mesh parts/materials:

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Random downvotes?